# CSS, selector in table

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking für a css-way to set td-attributes in tables with an special id.

I tried this:

```
table.myid > tr > td
{....}
```

but it seems that this 2 level parent-relation is not working.

any ideas??
I wont set class-ids in every td!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a class and not and ID.

I guess you dont have tables into tables, so try a simplest relantioship between the elements like

```
table#myid td {....}
```

It could free you from problems occuring because of "tbody" elements and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
table#myid > tr > td { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#myid td { your css }
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
#myid td {....}
```

or

```
.myclass td {....}
```

Is probally your best bet, not overly qualified and works in all browsers

you selector table.myid > tr > td {....} would not work when your tr is inside a tbody, thead or tfoot